# Как именно работают enum перечисления

Tags: c++

Не могу понять как работают перечисления с точки зрения выделения памяти.
Вот есть перечисление:

```
enum Colors
{
WHITE,
YELLOW,
GREEN
};
```

Память тут еще не выделена - ведь так? Мы по сути создали шаблон.
Но если память не выделена, то почему я могу присвоить переменной значение одного из перечислителей?

```
int main
{

int a = YELLOW;
}
```

int a получила значение 1, которое по умолчанию получил перечислитель YELLOW 1, но как?
Я ведь даже не создавал обьект типа Colors, как это нужно в случае enum class

Comment: enum это просто именование числовых констант, начиная с нулевой при неявном задании, либо вы можете присвоить значения сами ```YELLOW = 123,```

Comment: @SelfishCrawler то есть, перечислители инициализируются в момент обращения к ним?
А обьект типа перечисления не обязателен и нужен лишь для удобства уникализации значений перечислителей?

Comment: к вышеприведенному комменту добавлю, что каждый следующий элемент enum возрастает на +1 по отношению к предыдущему, если только вы самы не определяете значение этого элемента. Также стоит иметь ввиду, что значения элементов в enum может быть одинаковым, например: `enum Colors {Black = 0, White = 255, First = 0, Last = 255};`

Comment: @ReturnNullprt откуда вы это взяли? Ни о чем подобном вообще не говорилось

Comment: У вас не создается никакой объект и не выделяется память, формально компилятор ваш enum скорее всего попилит на тоже самое, что и ```#define YELLOW 1``` и заменит все ваши литеральные обозначения на числовые константы, таким образом превратив код в ```int a = 1;```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enum` объявляют не переменные, а именованные числа. Никаких областей памяти для этого не выделяется. Очень похоже работает макрос `define`.

```
# define dYELLOW 2
enum Colors { eYELLOW = 2 } ;
int x = dYELLOW ;
int y = eYELLOW ;
```

Но в `enum` есть область видимости в пространстве имён `Colors`. А в макросе до ручного уничтожения `#undef`.

Тип в перечислениях `enum` это `int` (по-умолчанию). А в макросе всё-что угодно.

---

Если непонятно, где все эти числа в программе, то посмотрите ассемблерный код :

```
x:
    .long   2
y:
    .long   2
```

В ассемблере есть переменные `x` и `y`. Им при старте программы заданы числа 2. Никаких именованных числел `dYELLOW` и `eYELLOW` в коде нет.

Comment: Под константы память как раз обычно выделяется.

Comment: Бюрократия , числа с именем устроит? @user7860670

Answer (score 4):

Вас же не смущает, например,

```
#define YELLOW 1
int a = YELLOW;
```

при том, что вы ничего не создавали? :) По сути, `enum` и есть, как вы сказали, шаблон. Только в нем, пока не сказано иное, нумерация идет от 0. Но вы в любой момент можете ее изменить -

```
enum Val {
    A,       // 0
    B,       // 1
    С = 15,  // 15
    D,       // 16 (продолжение счета)
    E        // 17
};
```

Comment: Про инициализиацию значениями и возможность их дублирования в курсе:)

Честно говоря, немного смущает момент:  
Ведь, когда мы инициализируем переменную, то она получает адрес в памяти. А  перечислитель, получается, просто хранит (ссылку - можно ли так сказать?) на литерал,и в случае, когда его вызывают, то заменяет себя этим литералом?

Comment: @ReturnNullptr все замены происходят еще во время компиляции. Когда программа работает, то этого перечисления фактически уже не существует.

Comment: Во время работы уже никаких литералов нет, они все - просто на время компиляции. В программе они заменяются конкретными числами. По сути, это для удобочитаемости :)